# Taking snapshot of Excel values not formulas

Tags: python, excel, formula, screenshot

I have an excel file, 90% of the numbers are hard coded values as 10% are formulas. When I try the following:

```
excel2img.export_img("excel.xlsx", result,"", "Sheet!A1:Z26")
```

I get a bunch of #VALUE errors unfortunately in the result. If I manually open the file (copy+save as bitmap) and take a screenshot by then, the formulas will show as values. I have also tried using win32 client and refreshing worksheet and other variations but to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide any more details? What fields are generating the `#VALUE` errors? Are any formulas referencing external files?

Comment: The formulas are v-lookups referencing external links. i.e. when I open the excel workbook, for a split second, the cells will show as #VALUE before reverting to the actual numbers. I have no problem saving the picture manually when I open up excel, but when I try with Python, it will capture the "#VALUE moments before it changes to actual numbers

Comment: Doesn't look like excel2img actually has any sort of ability to delay image capture or refresh formulas. I think you are seeing a product of Excel just taking a second to load.